# I want to initilize specific cells of a 2D array to 1. But my program keeps crashing

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[40] = {1,2,0,3,4,0,5,6,0,7,8,0,9,10,0,11,12,0,13,14,0,15,16,0,17,18,0,19,20,0,21,22,0,23,24,0,25,26,0,27};
    int i;
    int mat[27][27];

    //initilizing all cells of the matrix to zero
    for(int a=0 ; a<27 ; a++)
    {
        for(int b=0 ; b<27 ; b++)
        {
            mat[a][b]=0;
        }
    }

    //initilizing specific matix cells to 1
    for(int i=0 , j=1 ; j<39 ; j++)
    {
      if((j+1)%3 == 0)
      {
        j=j+2;
        i=i+3;
        mat[i][j]=1;
        /*cout<<arr[i]<<" ";  //Print array element
        cout<<arr[j]<<" ";*/
        continue;
      }
      mat[i][j]=1;
      /*cout<<arr[i]<<" ";  //Print array element
      cout<<arr[j]<<" ";*/
    } 

    //displaying matrix
    for(int c=0 ; c<27 ; c++)
    {
        for(int d=0 ; d<27 ; d++)
        {
            cout<<mat[c][d]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, what does "crashing" mean?  What is your output?

Comment: Have you tried compiling it with `-g` (GCC) and run through a debugger? E.g. `gdb ./a.out`. It will show you which line causes the crash.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], although with a clear description of what the problem is.

Comment: In the second `for` loop, you are using `or(int i=0 , j=1 ; j<39 ; j++)`. When the value of `j` is greater than 27, you end up accessing `mat` using an out of bounds index.

Comment: One of your for loops has j < 39, but your mat only has a size of 27 so it is out of bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your matrix is defined as `int mat[27][27]` but in your loop j can be > 26 (for example your loop goes to `j < 39`) which is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Eyal Cinamon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6312818/eyal-cinamon) and others, your loop second loop is going out of bounds and you're segfaulting.

A common way to avoid this error is to put your array bounds in a constant

```
const int MAT_MAX = 27;
int mat[MAT_MAX][MAT_MAX];

for (int i = 0, j = 1; j < MAT_MAX; j++)
{
    ...
}
```

also, as a nitpick, it's generally better to make a habit of using the prefix increment (`++j`) for incrementing your iterator. A smart compiler can probably optimise around it, but it's a good habit.